# Flutter: dart:io making a socket connection without using SSL (TLS) Certification

Tags: flutter, sockets, ssl, tor, dart-io

I am building a flutter project where I want to make GET requests to a .onion tor address (REST API). I found a good library: (https://pub.dev/packages/utopic_tor_onion_proxy), that allows you to do this, and i am using the dart:io libary to make socket connections. I can successfully make GET requests to adresses like: https://duckduckgogg42xjoc72x3sjasowoarfbgcmvfimaftt6twagswzczad.onion (duckduckgo).

But the code fails when opening a socket to my own .onion address. This is because i dont have a valid TLS certificate. Is it possible to make a socket connection with the dart:io library without using a TLS certificate?

code im using to make a socket connection (default from the utopic_tor_onion_proxy library):

```
import 'dart:io';
if (uri.scheme == 'https') {
_socket = await SecureSocket.secure(
_socket!,
host: uri.authority,
);
```

I want to have an option like:

```
allowInsecureConnection = true,
```

The same thing is easily possible with languages like python. For example:

```
import requests
session = requests.session()
session.proxies = {'https': 'socks5h://localhost:9150'}
r = session.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

Where **verify=False** solves the problem.

With CURL it is possible by adding `--insecure`

But I can't find a way to do it in flutter.

Here is the code I am using:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:utopic_tor_onion_proxy/utopic_tor_onion_proxy.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String? _torLocalPort;
  String? _error;
  String? _responseString;
  Socket? _socket;

  Future<void> _startTor() async {
    String? port;
    try {
      port = (await UtopicTorOnionProxy.startTor()).toString();
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e);
      _error = 'Failed to get port';
    }

    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      _torLocalPort = port;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _stopTor() async {
    try {
      if (await (UtopicTorOnionProxy.stopTor() as FutureOr<bool>)) {
        if (!mounted) return;
        setState(() {
          _torLocalPort = null;
        });
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e.message ?? '');
    }
  }

  Future<void> _sendGetRequest(Uri uri) async {
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        _responseString = null;
      });
    }
    _socket?.destroy();

    _socket = await Socket.connect(
      InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4,
      int.tryParse(_torLocalPort!)!,
      timeout: Duration(seconds: 5),
    );
    _socket!.setOption(SocketOption.tcpNoDelay, true);

    _socksConnectionRequest(uri, _socket!);

    List<int> responseIntList = [];

    void onSocketDone() {
      print('socket done');
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _responseString = String.fromCharCodes(responseIntList);
        });
      }
    }

    _socket!.listen((event) async {
      if (event.length == 8 && event[0] == 0x00 && event[1] == 0x5B) {
        print('Connection open');

        if (uri.scheme == 'https') {
          _socket = await SecureSocket.secure(
            _socket!,
            host: uri.authority,
          );
          _socket!.listen((event) {
            responseIntList.addAll(event);
          }).onDone(onSocketDone);
        }

        var requestString = 'GET ${uri.path} HTTP/1.1\r\n'
            'Host: ${uri.authority}\r\n\r\n';
        _socket!.write(requestString);
        return;
      }
      responseIntList.addAll(event);
    }).onDone(onSocketDone);
  }

  void _socksConnectionRequest(Uri uri, Socket socket) {
    var uriPortBytes = [(uri.port >> 8) & 0xFF, uri.port & 0xFF];
    var uriAuthorityAscii = ascii.encode(uri.authority);

    socket.add([
      0x04, // SOCKS version
      0x01, // request establish a TCP/IP stream connection
      ...uriPortBytes, // 2 bytes destination port
      0x00, // 4 bytes of destination ip
      0x00, // if socks4a and destination ip equals 0.0.0.NonZero
      0x00, // then we can pass destination domen after first 0x00 byte
      0x01,
      0x00,
      ...uriAuthorityAscii, // destination domen
      0x00,
    ]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Tor Onion Proxy example'),
        ),
        body: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constrains) {
            return Scrollbar(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: constrains.maxHeight),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(height: 20),
                      Text(
                          'Tor running on: ${_torLocalPort ?? _error ?? 'Unknown'}'),
                      SizedBox(height: 20),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                        child: Wrap(
                          runSpacing: 20,
                          spacing: 20,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            OutlinedButton(
                              child: Text('Start Tor Onion Proxy'),
                              onPressed:
                                  _torLocalPort == null ? _startTor : null,
                            ),
                            OutlinedButton(
                              child: Text('Stop Tor Onion Proxy'),
                              onPressed:
                                  _torLocalPort != null ? _stopTor : null,
                            ),
                            OutlinedButton(
                              child:
                                  Text('Send request to check.torproject.org'),
                              onPressed: _torLocalPort != null
                                  ? () => _sendGetRequest(
                                      Uri.https('xxxxxxx.onion:port', '/REST_CALL/'))
                                  : null,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      if (_responseString != null)
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                          child: Text('Response: \n\n$_responseString'),
                        ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _socket!.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Pass the `badCertificateCallback` parameter to `SecureSocket.secure()` - see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/SecureSocket/secure.html

Comment: Do you mean `badCertificateCallback` or `onBadCertificate`? Because I can't find `badCertificateCallback` on the site you referred.

Comment: Yes, `onBadCertificate`. (The other name is used on the HTTP client.)

Comment: I tried to add `onBadCertificate: (_) => true` in my `_socket = await SecureSocket.secure()`, but it doesn't work. I still get: `E/flutter (24574): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: HandshakeException: Connection terminated during handshake`. I am new to flutter and I couldn't find any documentation on 'onBadCertificate' to help me with this. Can you give me an example of how to use 'onBadCertificate' correctly in this case? Your help is very very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is my code now:   
 ```if (uri.scheme == 'https') {
 _socket = await SecureSocket.secure(
 _socket!,
 host: uri.authority,
 onBadCertificate: (_) => true,
 );
 print('prints if SecureSocket.secure() is succesful');```

Comment: Seems like a new problem now. Grab a packet capture and compare it with a working example from a working client.

Comment: Okay, so you're saying that the ssl certificate is not the problem and that `onBadCertificate: (_) => true' is the right way to disable ssl cert check?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. The problem was that I used `xxxxxxx.onion:port`. The '**:port**' was the problem.

Let's say the call was xxxxxxx.onion:1111. In the `void _socksConnectionRequest(Uri uri, Socket socket)` function, there is a uri.port and a uri.authority. the uri.port will be '1111', but the uri.authority will be xxxxxxx.onion:1111, therefore you have the port two times in the function. You can fix this by replacing: `var uriAuthorityAscii = ascii.encode(uri.authority);` with `var uriAuthorityAscii = ascii.encode(uri.authority.substring(0, uri.authority.length - 5));` in the _socksConnectionRequest function. this will make uri. authority = 'xxxxxxx.onion'. Note that I did -5 here, because our port is :1111, so it has 5 characters. If your port is:111, you must subtract 4. You can always replace this with a function if you have variable port length.

`onBadCertificate: (_) => true` was still needed in the `_socket = await SecureSocket.secure` function. It solved the `CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: self signed certificate(handshake.cc:393)) error.`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).